# How to Snapshot test Angular components with random div id

Tags: angular, tinymce, jestjs, snapshot

I am currently trying to set up snapshot testing on an Angular project using Jest. This project uses TinyMCE, and it is generating this HTML element in the snapshot:

```
<div id="tiny-angular_97712774031556003604487"/>
```

The number after the `tiny-angular_` is seemingly randomly generated, and changes every time I run the tests. As a result, the snapshot tests always fail. How can I get Jest to ignore that one div?